# Setting up ipsec/l2tp/psk VPN

Tags: 14.04, vpn, ipsec

I am having a hard time getting a VPN setup - can someone point me in the right direction? I am connecting to a fortigate firewall and need l2tp/ipsec/psk support - im using ubuntu studio 14.04

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and paste this, `sudo apt-get install strongswan network-manager-strongswan`

now if you go to the network-manager you should see the option to add IPSEC VPN. Hope this helps

Comment: the only apps in the software center for l2tp are for openswan - when i run apt-get install strongswan network-manager-strongswan -  it uninstalls openswan. --should i see ipsec/l2tp in the network manager after running apt-get install strongswan network-manager-strongswan ?

The only ipsec option i get in NM is IPSEC/IKEv2

Comment: Sorry I should have said to run this command in the terminal and not the software center. go to network manager after terminal install of the above posted command,  select edit connections/ add/ VPN/  ipsec ikev2  is what you should now see as an option

Comment: ok - so when configuring it i need to provide a PSK - the only place to provide it appears to be aking me to open a file - there is no file just a password/psk - where would i provide my psk?

Comment: I understood this is an IPSEC VPN and if that is correct these certificates or config files can be exported from the server

Comment: we are not provided a certificate - only a psk - as noted in the header

Comment: Sorry somehow I misunderstood, but I did find this, please have a look  https://my.hostvpn.com/knowledgebase/11/L2TPorIPSec-Connection-from-Ubuntu-Desktop-1204.html

Comment: i was using that for quite sometime - but a couple months ago it stopped working for me - now it just drops after a couple seconds

Comment: thanks for your help thus far on it - not too many people seemed to want to chime in -

Comment: Is it possible there was an update at work that may have caused the conflict for it to stop working? If it is hosted on a Windows server I know there was an Update not long ago that prevented PPTP connections from being successful from Ubuntu

Comment: Ahhh - it is hosted on a Win server then fortinet firewall - Thank You!!!  That explains so much!!!  Hopefully that issue gets worked out soon - Do you know of any work arounds (temp) for the possible pptp issue?

Comment: please upvote or mark as solved, so others can more easily find this solution